# Java decimal precision question

Tags: java

I have a problem which I have to print with long decimal places.
such as 
1/3 = 0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 (very very long)
when using C,
we can use
printf("%.30f", a);
but I don't know what to do using Java

Comment: *"Java decimal precision question"*  What question?  You forgot to ask one.  (Note that "I can't do X" is not a question.)

Answer (score 9):

You won't get that many decimal places of precision in IEEE754 binary floating point numbers in either C or Java. Your best bet would be to use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and perform the arithmetic with a particular precision. For example:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MathContext context = new MathContext(30);
        BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(3), context);
        System.out.println(result.toPlainString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.out.printf ([doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29))

Note, however that this is only for the same purpose as you are using printf in C: for simple debugging/learning.

When you need industrial strength precision, you need [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you could use printf as well, System.out.printf("...", a, b, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
 double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
            DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

Comment: Question was bad. But this code works and is the simplest way to go to round decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Java `double` and C/C++ `double` have the same precision. If you want to print 30 decimal places you can use

```
double d = 1.0/3;
System.out.println("%.30f", d);
```

However, double doesn't have 30 digits of precision (in any language) and you get a rounding error.  If you need 30 decimal places of precision in Java you need to use BigDecimal.